# Which is the best way for declare and get from input a char variable?

Tags: c, parameters

```
  char *variable;
  printf("write variable");
  scanf("%s",&variable);
```

I tried this part of code for get a char variable from input but it doesn't work. I don't know how to get it, can I have some tips?

Ps: Thanks for the help, and sorry for the basic question

Comment: `char *variable;` doesn't point anywhere. You need to [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) some memory.

Comment: Just about any beginners book or tutorial, good *and* bad, would have told you that this is wrong on many levels.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That's the least of the problems, actually.

Comment: `scanf("%s", foo);` needs a valid address `foo` that points to enough memory to hold the string you want to read plus one more byte for the terminating zero. That is, it needs to be a valid pointer to a string buffer. You've provided the address of a single character pointer. Do a google search or search on this site for "C reading string with scanf".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, I wouldn't say "least"...It's just as important as the other major error. And definitely more important than the minor issues (not checking return code from `scanf` and not specifying a max string width)

Comment: `scanf("%s")` is just as dangerous as `gets`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, the `%s` format specifier to `scanf` expects a `char *` argument pointing to a `char` array (either dynamically or statically allocated).  You're passing it a `char **`, which is an incompatible type.  Remove the address-of operator `&` to pass the correct type:

```
scanf("%s",variable);
```

Second, even with this fix, `variable` is uninitialized.  That means that `scanf` will attempt to write to an invalid memory address.  You need to either declare `variable` as an array:

```
char variable[50];
```

Or dynamically allocate memory for it:

```
char *variable = malloc(50);
```

You'll also need to specify a field width in the `scanf` specifier so it knows the maximum number of characters it can read:

```
scanf("%49s",variable);
```

Note that the field width is one less than the size of the array to leave room for the terminating null byte.

Answer (score 0):

You've used the & operator in scanf(it is used mostly), but for an string or array this does not work. Actually an array name is a pointer to first character of character array that mean it is the address of first character in character array. Now when you use & operator this passes address of address to first character of array, while required argument is of type char* and you're passing char**. Simply use as follow:

```
scanf("%s", mystring); // Good and works good
scanf("%s", &mystring); //bad and does not works
```